# SQL Error "One or more required Parameters are missing a value."

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Its telling me im missing a Parameter here, but I can't seem to figure out why. I have 2 Parameters, and 2 values given underneath the cmd statement.

Thanks in advance.

```
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Inventory SET CurBalDue = (CurBalDue + ?) WHERE CustID = ?", Con)

        Prm = New OleDbParameter("CurBalDue", Totcost)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

        Prm = New OleDbParameter("CustID", lblCustID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: You're re-using the same parameter object.  Maybe try creating a new one instead?

Comment: Im increasing that particular field in the Database though, by which I mean CurbalDue (its a number). If I changed that It would not work the way I want it too.

Comment: Changing the objects in code has no effect on data in the database.  All the code does is generate a query to send to the database.  All I'm suggesting is that it's *possible* that re-using the same `OleDbParameter` object is causing the error and that using two objects instead of one may correct the error.  It might be worth a try to at least *attempt* it as a fix.  Unless you also change something else, it won't change the query you send to the database.

Comment: So what you're saying is to not use "Prm" twice? Since in previous statements in the program I use it upwards of 15 times and they all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim SQl As string = "UPDATE Inventory SET CurBalDue = (CurBalDue + ?) 
        WHERE CustID = ?"      

Using cmd as New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Totcost)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", lblCustID.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using        ' dispose of the disposable
```

`AddWithValue` adds a new parameter to the collection, with a value in one step.  Also, OleDB does not support named params, so you are fooling yourself a little by using them as such.  They are just positional placeholders, add params in the order they appear in the SQL.

I have no way to tell what data type these critters are.  `Totcost` may well have to be converted:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToDecimal(Totcost))
```

Comment: There are risks associated with using `AddWithValue` - http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/